# What statistical test is appropriate? Binary dependent variable, categorical independent variable(s)

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients

I'm trying to understand the relationship based on survey data between one binary dependent variable (Did Give a Bribe for a Vaccine) and where the respondent lives (Urban, Peri-urban and Rural)  - the respondent can only select one of these. What statistical tests would be most appropriate?

Below is an sample of the data (N=5200). I've split the independent variables into separate columns but can put it back to one if needed. Ideally I'd like to know significance and strength of each predictor. Apologies if I've missed something here - I'm new to this.
Thanks!!

| Urban | Peri-Urban | Rural | (dependent) Did Give a Bribe for a Vaccine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Follow up question - I assume I cant use linear regression, but what about logistic?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Logistic regression is making sense to me. How would you perform and interpret it?

Comment: Logistic regression is an option, but note that you would only two of the dummy variables (*Urban*, *Peri-urban*, *Rural*).  You could also summarize the data into a table of counts (contingency table) with two dimensions:  *Bribe* vs. *Location*, which would be a 2 x 3 table.  You could then use a chi-square test of association or related test.

Comment: @SalMangiafico thankyou! "you would only two of the" did you mean to add "use" in there? if so why is that the case?

Comment: @Dave it may be blasphemous here but im just using Excel at the moment. im not sure how i'd interpret it yet!

Comment: Also note that your sample size is quite large.  You will likely find a small *p*-value for a test of the  coefficient from logistic regression or a test of the contingency table.  You will likely want to rely on some measure of effect size for interpretation.  Maybe odds ratio.  Or the proportion of *Bribe Yes* for each *Location*.

Comment: Yes, "use".  The values for *Urban* and *Peri-urban* perfectly predict the value for *Rural*.  So you can't put all three of them in the model.  This is sometimes called the "dummy variable trap".  (Maybe see, [SE link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590741/about-dummy-variable-trap)).

Answer (score 0):

***Answer from comments:***

Logistic regression is an option, but note that you would use only two of the dummy variables (*Urban*, *Peri-urban*, *Rural*).  The values for *Urban* and *Peri-urban* perfectly predict the value for *Rural*. So you can't put all three of them in the model. This is sometimes called the "dummy variable trap". (Maybe see, SE link: [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590741/about-dummy-variable-trap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590741/about-dummy-variable-trap)).

You could also summarize the data into a table of counts (contingency table) with two dimensions: *Bribe* vs. *Location*, which would be a 2 x 3 table. You could then use a chi-square test of association or related test.

Also note that your sample size is quite large. You will likely find a small *p*-value for a test of the coefficient from logistic regression or for a test of the contingency table.

You will likely want to rely on some measure of effect size for interpretation. Maybe odds ratio. Or the proportion of *Bribe Yes* for each *Location*.