# Proof of linear independence of dummy encoding

Tags: regression, machine-learning, categorical-encoding, linear-algebra

I understand one-hot encoding is linearly dependent and if I drop one column, it would become linear independent, but I don't know how to prove it, can someone give me a mathematical proof.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence):

> A sequence of vectors $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \dots,
>  \mathbf{v}_k$ from a vector space $V$ is said to be linearly
> dependent, if there exist scalars $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k$, not all
> zero, such that
>
> $$a_1\mathbf{v}_1 + a_2\mathbf{v}_2 + \cdots + a_k\mathbf{v}_k =
>  \mathbf{0},$$
>
> where $\mathbf{0}$ denotes the zero vector.

One-hot encoded matrix looks like

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

now add an intercept to the matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}  
$$

You should not have problems finding non-zero vectors such that after multiplying the new matrix by them you would get zero vectors (e.g. $(-\pi, \pi, \pi, \pi)$). This shows that the columns are linearly dependent, so multicollinear. [That is why](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224051/one-hot-vs-dummy-encoding-in-scikit-learn) we [drop one of the columns](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231285/dropping-one-of-the-columns-when-using-one-hot-encoding?rq=1) per each feature.

Comment: Dropping a column in (3) will not create linearly independent columns.

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't fix the example!  The rank of the matrix in $(3)$ is $3,$ implying you would have to drop at least three columns before the remaining ones are linearly independent.