# Dummy / Reference variable in LASSO (group lasso)

Tags: lasso, categorical-encoding

I am performing group lasso and need to double check if I include a dummy variable for the reference answer or not. For example:

original question : no (0), Yes (1), Unknown (9).

If I create 3 dummy variables, no (reference) (0/1), yes (0/1), and unknown (0/1), would I include all three in the group lasso or just the 2 (yes and unknown).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter because you are using regularization. Without regularization, you would have [too many parameters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224051/one-hot-vs-dummy-encoding-in-scikit-learn), but it's [not a problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/168622/35989) for a regularized model. So you can use either. Including all the categories is a popular choice for regularized models though, as you don't need to decide which category to drop.

Comment: For my logistic regression model, after regularization. Would I include all three parameters (no/yes/unk) or only the two yes/unk and leave the reference out?

Comment: @LeviM as said above, it's up to you, both are ok.

Comment: Ok, thank you for confirming so quickly!