# Dummy Variable Trap in KMeans Clustering

Tags: clustering, k-means, categorical-encoding

My data set is having a column **Gender**, so I have to apply One Hot Encodingto perform `KMeans Clustering`.

**Q1.** *Should I take care about `dummy variable trap` here ?, should I remove one of the dummy columns ?*

**Q2.** *Should I use `Label Encoding` or `One Hot Encoding` in case of Clustering Algorithms ?*

Comment: It is improper to do k-means clustering with _categorical_ data. Well, it is sometimes used with naturally binary data such as _p_ attributes, each can be present (1) or absent (0). In this case, one could argue that the 0-1 scale is a binned scale of the "original" unobserved or underlying continuos scale. On the ground of this idea they indulge in k-means. But categorical data such as "city" - it cannot be thought of as a simply binned continuous variable or a set of those. Irrespective of how you choose encode. (As a predictor in a regression - you can. But not in a cluster analysis.)

Answer (score 0):

- Dummy variable trap is a problem only in classical regression models. It is not a problem for most of the machine learning models, including things like regularized regression.
- Label encoding is a *poor* way of encoding categorical data. If you encode {red, green, blue} as {1, 2, 3} you are implicitly assuming that the categories have numerical sense, so for example red + 2 = blue, which doesn't make sense. Rarely it is a valid choice.
- You should use dummy encoding or one-hot encoding. For the difference between them check the [One-hot vs dummy encoding in Scikit-learn](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224051/one-hot-vs-dummy-encoding-in-scikit-learn) thread. TL;DR dummy encoding is one-hot encoding with one of the categories dropped, in some cases, you use one, in other another.
- If your “gender” feature has only two categories you can use dummy coding, i.e. a column of zeros and ones. One-hot encoding would introduce a redundant column, so it is rarely used for two categories. On another hand, if your “gender” feature has more categories, one-hot encoding may make sense.

Comment: So, I should not be afraid of dummy variable trap in other ML models rather than the regression models, right ?

Comment: I prefer to think that dummy coding and one-hot coding are synonyms. More formal name for it is "indicator type of contrast (en)coding". Dummy is an older argo from statistics while one-hot is a younger one from machine learning. Both this and that can be with or without dropping of the "redundant" category.